# How to pass a PHP variable retrieved from database from one php page to another php page

Tags: javascript, php

```html
<?php

$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','practice');

if($con->connect_error)
{
 echo "".connect_error;
}

$quer = "select * from form";

$result= $con->query($quer);
echo "<h1>Edit/Remove</h1>";
echo "<table border=1><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Email</th><th>Password</th><th>Month</th><th>Day</th><th>Year</th>
<th>Gender</th><th>Telugu</th><th>Hindi</th><th>English</th>
<th>Mobile</th><th>Location</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";
if($result->num_rows >0)
{
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$row['Firstname']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Lastname']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Email']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Password']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Month']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Day']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Year'].
  "</td>"."<td>".$row['Gender']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Telugu']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Hindi']."</td>"."<td>".$row['English']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Mobile']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Location']."</td>";
   echo "<td><form method='post' action='update.php' ><input type='hidden' name= 'email' value='".$row['Email']."'><input type='submit' value='edit'>
   </form></td>"."<td><form method='post' action='delete.php' ><input type='hidden' name= 'email' value='".$row['Email']."'><input type='submit' value='delete'>
   </form></td>";
     echo "</tr>";
 }
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='form.html'>Home</a>";
$con->close();
?>
```

I have created a edit/delete options in my form retrieved from database using php can I do this with javascript.

I want to replace the form tag in the code with button and perform the action with onclick - can I do this without jQuery or json?

Comment: By hidden input

Comment: or by `sessions` and `cookies`

Comment: i used hidden input only is there any other way

Comment: Yeah. There is absolutely an another way. But it is not as safe as you're doing with forms.

Comment: can u give an example snippet

Comment: You could use query string parameters (ie. `delete.php?id=x`) - but as mentioned, the hidden input is a better method and will work with JavaScript disabled too - whereas onclick will not.